# Call to a member function pluck() on null

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.7

i have a problem and error :

this is error:

**Call to a member function pluck() on null**

```
    protected function setCourseTime($episode)
{
    $course = $episode->course;
    $course->time = $this->getCourseTime($course->episodes->pluck('time'));
    $course->save();
}

protected function getCourseTime($times)
{
    $timestamp = Carbon::parse('00:00:00');
    foreach ($times as $t) {
        $time = strlen($t) == 5 ? strtotime('00:' . $t) : strtotime($t);
        $timestamp->addSecond($time);
    }
    return $timestamp->format('H:i:s');
}
```

}

Thanks for your help

Laravel version : 5.7
php version : 7.0.2

Comment: show us your relationship of model

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your relationship is defined similar to this:

```
public function episodes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Episode::class);
}
```

If you miss `return` here, `$course->episodes` will return `null` so it's impossible to run `pluck` on null.

Comment: Thnaks for your answer . but it is not my problem and my relationships is like yours code !

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have defined the 'episodes' relationship on the course model.

Note this. `$course->episodes` will fetch episodes from the database as a 'Collection'.

But if you only need the `time` of the episodes, filter them right from the database.

what you should do is `$course->episodes()` **note the brackets**.
This will call the 'episodes' relationship. then you can call  `pluck()`.

```
$course->episodes()->pluck('time')
```

Comment: It's not true. There is `pluck` method in Collection: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-pluck and this one will be run if there are any results

Comment: @SeyedMasihTabaei note that  as @MarcinNabiałek pointed out, you can call `pluck()` function on the 'Collection instance' too.  But since this approach is more efficient, I updated the answer

Comment: Ok thanks you for efficient help !(sorry for my bad English)